# How to extract feature_importances_ and lr.coef_ from a model created by GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, grid-search

How do I extract `feature_importances_` and `lr.coef_` from a model created by GridSearchCV? I have tried manually fitting the model with the tuned hyperparameters to be able to use the functions but the results (i.e. `auc`) are different.

```
pipelines = {
'rf' : make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), 
RandomForestClassifier(random_state=521)),
'l1' : make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression(penalty='l1' , 
random_state=521))
}

rf_hyperparams = {
'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [100, 110],
'randomforestclassifier__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt']
}

l1_hyperparams = {
'logisticregression__C': np.linspace(1e-3, 10)
}

hyperparams = {
'rf' : rf_hyperparams,
'l1' : l1_hyperparams
}

fitted = {}
for name, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparams[name], cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    fitted[name] = model
```